# ifstream in HTML only Javascript without Jquery

Tags: ifstream

In my static HTML page, I cannot use Jquery. I want a button to load a webpage inside my iframe.

`<input type="button" value="See" id="but" onclick="document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML='Hello'"/>
<iframe id="iframe" name="myIframe" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>`

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes have a source, not innerHtml

```js
document.getElementById('but').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('iframe').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape('Hello')
})
```

```html
<input type="button" value="See" id="but" />
<iframe id="iframe" name="myIframe" width="90%" height="90%"></iframe>
```